# How to send data from a React form to the Wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, next.js, content-management-system, wordpress-rest-api

For example, I have a form in React (I also use Next.js) and I want to send data from it to the Wordpress admin panel. It's like a Headless CMS. So that the moderator goes into the WP admin area and processes all requests. How to do this and how to display them correctly in the admin panel? (I have these fields in the form: first Name, last Name, email, phone number, company name, Topic of Inquiry, Your message (optional).

Accordingly, I need some kind of custom table to display all these fields in the best way implement everything?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.